# Clearing some things out about JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery

1. What is the different between `$.get` method and `$.post` method?
2. When is which one is better?
3. `$.Ajax` is better than above things y we are using `.get` and `.post` method?

Comment: Ajax simply does get or post requests in the background, instead of replacing the entire page at once, it replaces a piece of the page. You can certainly build web apps that never talk to the server (Javascript in the browser) that don't use get or post but the Ajax you claim is better than get and post is pretty boring without get and post.

Comment: While the question isn't necessarily great, he's talking about the $.get and $.post jQuery methods, which are both implementations of AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` and `$.post` are subsets of the `$.ajax` method.

They're already set up for `GET` and `POST` requests and make it easier and quicker to code, in addition to making your code more readable.

`$.ajax` offers more control, but at the expense of readability, and speed (in terms of coding). It's more extensible, so is suited for functions where your standard `$.get` or `$.post` may not be sufficient.

Use whichever works for you. If all you're doing is trying to `POST` data, then `$.post` let's you do this simply. If you want more control, use `$.ajax`.

Comment: Also, most of the time when I decide to use `$.ajax` over `$.post` or `$.get`, it's because it has better handling for errors (see the `error` setting on the [`$.ajax` page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). It's, of course, more powerful than that, but it's particularly common to want some error handling beyond guessing whether the `success` function fires.

Comment: different between $.get method and $.post method, pls descripbe any unique points?

Comment: One uses GET, the other uses POST. If you need more then that, you probably want to get some basic knowledge about request types.